# Use multiple datasource in one crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, redbrick

I am using crystal reports 2008, I want to use multiple data sources in one report. One is connecting informix and another is connecting redbrick data source. Both are independent data source and doesnt have any common value to co -relate them. Can we have that option?
Pleae advice?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it already? Crystal Reports allows you to add tables, via Database Expert, from multiple datasources. It will warn you that it *may* not work, but many times it does.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
But now its OK after using subreport.
ie. Create the subreport with just the details section and put in inside the main report.

According to my colleague,
For "independent data sources", that have no relationship at all,
we should use subreport.